# How to store vicinity and address with Google Places Api Actions in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

I'm trying to save a new place with Android using Google Places Api Actions. In order to do so, I've downloaded this simple library which works fine.

https://github.com/windy1/google-places-api-java#add-place

If I create a new place with the standard methods, the place is visible with the scope APP as expected.

```
            //In my AsyncTask Method: 
             GooglePlaces client = new GooglePlaces("MY API KEY");


            double lat = 45.231745;
            double lng = 10.248884;

            try{

                se.walkercrou.places.Place place = client.addPlace("Test Location", "it", lat, lng, 50, "bar");

            }catch(Exception e){

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

However I want to be able to store also the address field and the vicinity field. Reading the docs and the code of the library this can be done by adding two extra parameters to the method addPlace, like so :

```
             GooglePlaces client = new GooglePlaces("MY API KEY");

            double lat = 45.231745;
            double lng = 10.248884;

            try{

                Param p = Param.name("vicinity");
                p.value("My example address 6, CR Italy");

                Param p2 = Param.name("address");
                p2.value("My example address 6, CR Italy");


                se.walkercrou.places.Place place = client.addPlace("Test Location2", "it", lat, lng, 50, "bar",p,p2);



            }catch(Exception e){

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

The method does not give any error. However, the stored place does not contain the vicinity parameter. This is the response that I get when I call the method to list places:

```
{
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 45.231745,
           "lng" : 10.248884
        }
     },
     "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/bar-71.png",
     "id" : "344d2ffcb408cfefcb6ff137e0c8dcbb0cea901d",
     "name" : "Test Location2",
     "place_id" : "qgYvCi0wMDAwMDA5Y2UwYThjNGM5OjQ3ODFhZWJlZGM3OjBiNWZmNGIxZTNmNDFlYzU",
     "reference" : "CnRqAAAAjSMpi9N2keFELpIekQ1-b2_RJKeCVLhC9lpxvqoZZqgtgftpVJMeGiAk4F_uHLXu9UUeuIWYLJk2jhVMyq3-P09PwqLelQRvJy3bCeEqnNJSdf_OGHUFRaXV7mKjoyUBSiCWY4C9dOwxsv6IYRbf8xIQjtIH5FP5NVE7toep-PJUOBoUsSeWqsTD6PZuEF8aE3PX0sJmYIA",
     "scope" : "APP",
     "types" : [ "bar", "establishment" ]
  }
```

The place is there but with no address or vicinity. What am I doing wrong?

I've also tried to implement my own version of the method, using a simple `http post` request:

```
public String addPlaceMap() {

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000); // Timeout
String result=null;                                                                     // Limit
HttpResponse response;

JSONObject placeJson =  new JSONObject();
JSONObject location = new JSONObject();
try {
location.put("lat", 45.231745);
location.put("lng", 10.248884);
placeJson.put("name", "Test 1");
placeJson.put("location", location);
placeJson.put("accuracy", 50);

JSONArray jarr = new JSONArray();
jarr.put("bar");
placeJson.put("types", jarr);
placeJson.put("vicinity", "My test address 1, Cremona Italy");
placeJson.put("address", "My test address 1, Cremona Italy");
placeJson.put("language", "it");


    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/add/json?key=MY API KEY");
    post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(placeJson.toString());
    post.setEntity(se);
    response = client.execute(post);

    if (response == null) {


        return null;
    }

    if (response != null) {
        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent(); 
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(in, "iso-8859-1"));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");

        String line = "0";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        in.close();
        result = sb.toString();

        Log.i("RESULT", result);

    return result;  

    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
}
return null;

 }
```

In this case I get a successful response from Google. However, the vicinity is still not visibile. What am I doing wrong? Is this field not visible until Google validation?

Comment: "The types parameter may be a single type or a collection of types". Have you tried to pass the `types` as an `array` or `struct` of `types` instead?

Comment: change `placeJson.put("address", "My test address 1, Cremona Italy");` to `placeJson.put("formatted_address", "My test address 1, Cremona Italy");`. Also, note that the field `language` is not a valid field, maybe you cannot save the whole thing unless you provide a valid JSON

Comment: Well, very strange. I have double checked and now if I'll put placeJson.put("address", "My test address 1, Cremona Italy") is visibile in getdetails but not visibile in nearbysearch. In the getdetails also is visibile as "formatted_address" : "MyADD"  ... even if I've putted "address" in the placeJson

Comment: "result":{"formatted_address" :"MyAdd","geometry":{"location":{"lat":45.231745,"lng":10.248884}},"icon":"http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/bar-71.png","id" : "ff25a94490544a3a8d70d9427080d7aeb017e200","name":"Test O001","place_id":"qgYvCi0wMDAwMDA5Y2UwYThjNGM5OjQ3ODFhZWJlZGM3OjI4NWNhMmJhOTIwZDI2MWI","reference" :"CmRdAAAAsy3haI9dIzTSj1U8g38Hb6ACzng0gz9ql53JzpXNOMjowlD1JXe522YdEkmfrWUGVnyBJWQEPexE3C2at4rgaaqls4--vZ4UAAU8Js9nKGQIu2nRPZkF_8VXQhS0xA7vEhCmfP9RSAw29XwCTQcNzSBvGhSOUrjyD0QNGCIp6GfmJQOQjLoAbw","scope":"APP","types":[ "bar","establishment"]},"status":"OK"}

Comment: well I don't really know what else to tell you, sorry...let's hope you find a helpful post or someone posts a working solution. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to give a specific format to those fields. See if [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details_responses) helps.

Comment: I've tried to read all the documentation on the link that you gave me, however it seems that the format is correct. In fact I have this response from Google : {
"id" : "4f4b90f9b856c66d3f06dc3431bf6faa8ea7246a",
"place_id" : "qgYvCi0wMDAwMDA5Y2UwYThjNGM5OjQ3ODFhZWJlZGM3OjM0ZmYxZTMzZGUzNDEwYjA",
"reference" : "CkQxAAAALyreTClPU-bpAcjkipEWMfmwSwF7pp0kmHBNNnORRnd0Ty1NXRHx9PFZMDTIMy3exZLR81agdWLbhDdQzSg6bxIQGbbx5YSoy_m9K5H0YgDvlhoUR5fpmvNpmZnlx0ehec7MWTVUH8c",
"scope" : "APP",
 "status" : "OK"
}     however no address or vicinity are returned or saved

Comment: weird...I assume you are calling `getDetails()` for accessing the data, right? In that case I would double-check for spelling mistakes.

Comment: Yes,I get this: {"html_attributions" : [],"result" : {"geometry" : {"location":{"lat":45.231745,"lng":10.248884}},"icon":"http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/bar-71.png","id": "42f6e7ff7851d150d45e574de5621197440ab6ed","name":"Test O50","place_id":"qgYvCi0wMDAwMDA5Y2UwYThjNGM5OjQ3ODFhZWJlZGM3OjJkMTk3Zjg1OTVhMGRlYTU","reference":"CmRcAAAA1952muw_QRbOXrUg6YPWybGNQAOr2x2N9Qne6G5anxd2gmDDcsHw9psa34JSFAmGWMv6Lq1URyjizROxnQ02_fK43-kyl83jPU-oIqxmMS65LV3P3qzNYkVS56niUyx9EhDY7x1hpYS05H4FAnN1u00wGhR1MAivtJ0xGZqcWGXtExWsb-Dguw","scope":"APP","types":["bar","establishment" ]},"status":"OK"}

Comment: please try parsing the types as `type1|type2|type3|etc`, like they suggest here: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search?hl=es